# Default value for some key in MySQL query's result instead of `null`

Tags: mysql, database

I have a query that select statuses from table `status` and likes for each status:

```
SELECT
    status.id
  , concat('[',(SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('username', l.whoLiked)) FROM `like` l WHERE l.status = status.id),
    ']') AS likes
FROM
  user,
  user statusAuthor
  INNER JOIN status ON statusAuthor.username = status.author
WHERE
  user.username = 'someuser' AND status.replyTo IS NULL;
```

Here is my problem:

```
concat('[',(SELECT
          GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('username', l.whoLiked)) FROM `like` l WHERE l.status = status.id),
        ']') AS likes
```

If for status no likes I've get `null`:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "likes": null,
}
```

If status has likes I've get an array:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "likes": [
        {
            "username": "ax"
        },
        {
            "username": "dav"
        }
    ],
}
```

Can I do by default an empty array as a value of `likes` key instead of `null`?

Comment: Have a look at `COALESCE(yourcode, '[]')`

Comment: @Pharaoh thanks a lot!

Comment: I have added it as an answer so this question can rest in peace :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `COALESCE` function. It returns the first argument that is not `null`.

You could use it like that:

```
COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('username', l.whoLiked)), '[]')
```